# PDF to bytearrayoutpustream whitespace

Tags: pdf, blob, bytearrayoutputstream

I've a java code to create a PDF temporary file and save it into a BLOB field DB. PDF is generated correctly, and BLOB is saved into DB. When I recreate PDF this is returned without whitespace char! Probably the problem is codification Base64 of bytearrayoutputstream. This is  my code

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream generaFatturaStampaPDF(Fattura fattura) {
    try {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 72, 72, 120, 90);

        String tempdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

        if ( !(tempdir.endsWith("/") || tempdir.endsWith("\\")) )
           tempdir = tempdir + System.getProperty("file.separator");

        File tempFattura = File.createTempFile("fattura",".pdf", new File(tempdir));
        tempFattura.deleteOnExit();

        setFileTempFattura(tempFattura.toString());

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(tempFattura));
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter());

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter docWriter = null;
        docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        docWriter.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        docWriter.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter());


        document.open();
        addMetaDataFattura(document);

        Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph paragrafoFattura = new Paragraph();
        paragrafoFattura.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        Chunk c = new Chunk("Fattura");
        c.setFont(catFont);
        paragrafoFattura.add(c);
        document.add(paragrafoFattura);

        intestazioneFatturaStampa(writer, fattura);
        intestazioneFatturaStampa(docWriter, fattura);
        addEmptyLine(document, 7);

        float[] widths = { 8f, 2f };
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(widths);
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        addCenterTableHeaderBold(table, "Descrizione", true, 12);
        addCenterTableHeaderBold(table, "Totale", true, 12);

        Double somma = 0.0;
        Iterator<FatturaDettaglio> iterator = fattura.getFatturaDettaglios().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FatturaDettaglio fatturaDettaglio = iterator.next();
            somma += fatturaDettaglio.getPrezzo();
        }
        addCenterTableHeaderBoldAllignLeft(table, fattura.getFatturaDettaglios().size()
                + " Richieste di Preventivo ", false, 12);
        addCenterTableHeaderBold(table, "€ " + arrotonda(somma), false, 12);

        Iterator<CreditoDebito> iterator2 = fattura.getCreditoDebitos().iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            CreditoDebito creditoDebito = iterator2.next();

            addCenterTableHeaderBoldAllignLeft(table, creditoDebito.getNote(), false, 12);
            String segno = "";
            if (creditoDebito.getTipo().equals("C")) {
                segno = "-";
                somma = somma - creditoDebito.getImporto();
            }
            if (creditoDebito.getTipo().equals("D")) {
                segno = "";
                somma = somma + creditoDebito.getImporto();
            }
            addCenterTableHeaderBold(table, "€ " + segno
                    + arrotonda(creditoDebito.getImporto()), false, 12);
        }

        document.add(table);

        addEmptyLine(document, 2);

        float[] widths1 = { 2f, 1f };
        PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(widths1);
        table1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        table1.setWidthPercentage(60);

        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "Totale Imponibile netto", true);
        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "€ " + arrotonda(somma), false);

        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "IVA", true);
        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "€ " + arrotonda(somma * 20 / 100), false);

        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "Totale Fattura", true);
        addCenterTableHeader(table1, "€ " + arrotonda(somma + somma * 20 / 100), false);

        document.add(table1);

        addEmptyLine(document, 2);

        paragrafoFattura.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        Chunk datiPagamento =
                new Chunk("Dettagli pagamento:\nMetodo: "
                        + fattura.getAzienda().getMetodoPagamento()
                        + "\nIBAN:  IT xx X xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx");
        document.add(datiPagamento);
        addEmptyLine(document, 5);
        Chunk dettagliEstrattoContoTesto =
                new Chunk(
                        "Per maggiori dettagli sulle richieste di preventivo e eventuali promozioni consultare l'estratto conto allegato");
        dettagliEstrattoContoTesto.setFont(new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10,
                Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
        document.add(dettagliEstrattoContoTesto);
        document.close();
        docWriter.close();

        return baos;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by without whitespace char? From what and where is the whitespace missing?

Comment: when I recreate PDF this string "Per maggiori dettagli sulle richieste di preventivo e eventuali promozioni consultare l'estratto conto allegato" is write as this "Permaggioridettaglisullerichiestedipreventivoeeventualipromozioniconsultarel'estrattocontoallegato"

Comment: PDF files can't be modified without becoming entirely corrupt, so if something changed in the file then it is unlikely that you would even be able to open it. Are you certain this error does not occur in your original? Also, why do you need base64 encoding? Can't you store it as binary?

Comment: PDF files are OK! The code above create PDF file and some time copy this document into ByteArrayOutputStream 'PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);'
PDF is correct and baos is stored into DB. With another method I recreate PDF file from DB data, and in this file (a correct PDF file) string whitespace is ignored!

Comment: Sorry Claudio, you're not making much sense. You need to find a way to communicate the problem more clearly in order for something to be able to help. I don't understand from where or when this problem is occurring.

Comment: 1. create PDF file
2. create ByteArrayOutputStream to store PDF into DB
3. PDF file is temporary and was delete 
4. I try to recreate PDF from ByteArrayOutputstrem saved into DB
5. PDF are recreate correctly but all string is write without space!
this is the step, and problem is at point 5

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the string containing the PDF first, then putting it into the DB compressed, then uncompress it when pulling it out. This will ensure that nothing is changed and the string is handled as binary.

Comment: I created a method that creates a temporary PDF file with iText and simultaneously create a ByteArrayOutputStream in which I copy the contents of the PDF file and then save ByteArrayOutputStream with another method.PDF file is sent via email and is correct. Then I created another method that returns me the PDF output from the DB, however. This file is returned to me, however, with the spaces between shakes eliminated: to be clear if I have the original PDF in the sentence: "For more information" regenerated in the PDF file from the DB I: "Formoreinformation". What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try what I said? If there is still a problem then the problem is with the transmission over email, not from the database, which you were implying originally.